# Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed IOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

i'm using mac mini M1

i getting error on live reload run app on iPhoneX(14.7.1),
when i reload app from device debug menu it will be reloaded on reload click
but when i press R in terminal showing warning

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Reloading app...
```